# How to use "Input.GetButtonDown" in the new Input System?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a 2d platformer game with Unity using the new Input System and Player Input component.
I want to make a shooting system for the game but I need to use "Input.GetButtonDown" which is for the old Input System. Is there any equivalent for it and if not, how can I make this in the new Input System?

Here's my player controller code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions
 {
   private PlayerInputActions controls;     
   private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private Animator anim;
   private bool facingRight = true;
    private Vector2 moveInput;


 [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    float JumpPressedRemember = 0;
   
   [SerializeField] float JumpPressedRememberTime = 0.2f;
    float GroundedRemember = 0;
     
   [SerializeField]  float GroundedRememberTime = 0.25f;  
   [SerializeField]  float HorizontalAcceleration = 1;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingBasic = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenStopping = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenTurning = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float JumpHeight = 0.5f;

   private void Awake() 
   {
      controls = new PlayerInputActions();

      controls.Player.SetCallbacks(this);
    }
     void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();       
}
   void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
      moveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
          
   }

   void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
       jumpForce = context.ReadValue<float>();
       switch (context.phase)
       {
            case InputActionPhase.Performed:
               this.Jump();
               break;
       }
   }
   
   public void Jump()
   {
     rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * this.jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
   }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {

   if(facingRight == false && moveInput.x > 0){
   
    Flip();
   
   }else if (facingRight == true && moveInput.x < 0){
    
    Flip();

   }
 }
    void Flip(){
    
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
   transform.localScale = Scaler;
 } 

 void OnEnable()
 {
     controls.Enable();
 }
 
 void OnDisable()
 {
     controls.Disable();
 }
 void Update()
  {

   Vector2 GroundedBoxCheckPosition = (Vector2)transform.position + new Vector2(0, -0.01f);
   Vector2  GroundedBoxCheckScale = (Vector2)transform.localScale + new Vector2(-0.02f, 0);
   bool Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(GroundedBoxCheckPosition, transform.localScale, 0);
    
    GroundedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Grounded)
    {
      GroundedRemember = GroundedRememberTime;
    }

    JumpPressedRemember -= Time.deltaTime; 
   if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
   {
      JumpPressedRemember = JumpPressedRememberTime;
   }
     if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * JumpHeight);
            }
        }
    if ((JumpPressedRemember > 0) && (GroundedRemember > 0))
    {
       JumpPressedRemember = 0;
       GroundedRemember = 0;

      rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }
     float HorizontalVelocity = rb.velocity.x;
      HorizontalVelocity += moveInput.x;
          
    
        if (Mathf.Abs(moveInput.x) < 0.01f)
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenStopping, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
           else if (Mathf.Sign(moveInput.x) != Mathf.Sign(HorizontalVelocity))
           HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        else
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingBasic, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalVelocity, rb.velocity.y);

        
  }
}
```

[image: And this is the Input Actions window.]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This seems to be answered by Unity's own documentation on [Migrating from the old Input System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Migration.html):

> **UnityEngine.input.GetButtonDown**
>
> See [UnityEngine.Input.GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Migration.html#getAxis) for how to set up a Binding to a button or axis. You can use the [press Interaction](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Interactions.html#press) to detect when a button is pressed.
>
> You can also use [ButtonControl.wasPressedThisFrame](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls.ButtonControl.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_Controls_ButtonControl_wasPressedThisFrame) to detect if a button Control was pressed down this frame directly without using Bindings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read Unity's documentation but I'm confused now. Could you please show me an example on how to convert these lines with press Interaction?             
    
        "if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        
    }"

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to understand the documentation and write the code but I didn't understand how to use "Press Interaction" with "started" and "performed''.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer in a topic which is not well documented at the moment for beginners.